# UDP server/client not working with 127.0.0.1 on Ubuntu bind call returning an error number 99

Tags: c, sockets, udp

I am trying to implement the UDP client /server on Ubuntu, I tried to bind the socket to local host (127.0.0.1) but bind is returning the error number 99. I tried different ports also but in vain. Please find the code `udpserver.c` and `udpclient.c` respectively

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<errno.h>

int main()
{
    int udpsocket = 0, ret = 0 , length = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in server, client;
    char buffer[1024];
    udpsocket = socket (AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM , 0 );
    if ( udpsocket == -1)
    {
        printf("Error in creating udp socket \n");
        return -1;
    };
    memset(&server, 0 , sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) );
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(16000);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    ret = bind ( udpsocket, (struct sockaddr*)&server, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in) );
    if (ret == -1)
    {
        printf("Errno is %d \n", errno);
        printf("Error in binding the socket \n" );
        close(udpsocket);
    }
    memset(buffer, 0 , 1024);
    length = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    while (1)
    {
        recvfrom(udpsocket, buffer , 1024, 0,(struct sockaddr*)&client, (socklen_t *)&length);
        if (! strcmp(buffer,"bye") )
        break;
        if ( buffer[0] != '\0' )
        printf("message is %s \n", buffer );
        memset(buffer, 0 , 1024);
    }
    close(udpsocket);
    return 0;
}

#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>

int main()
{
    int udpsocket = 0, ret = 0 , length = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in server;
    char buffer[1024];
    udpsocket = socket(AF_INET , SOCK_STREAM, 0 );
    if ( udpsocket == -1 )
    {
        return -1;
    }
    memset(&server, 0 , sizeof(struct sockaddr_in ) );
    server.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    server.sin_port = htons(16000);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(inet_addr("127.0.0.1") );
    memset(buffer, 0 ,1024);
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf("Enter message \n");
        scanf("%s",&buffer );
        if ( buffer[strlen(buffer)] == '\n' )
        buffer[strlen(buffer)] = '\0';
        length = strlen(buffer) + 1;
        sendto(udpsocket, buffer, length, 0 , (struct sockaddr_in*)&server, (socklen_t*)&length);
        if ( !strcmp(buffer,"bye") ) break;
    }
    close(udpsocket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if ( buffer[strlen(buffer)] == '\n' )`This condition will never be true.